# CanCan and Mongoid "or" do not play nice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, cancan

I want to get all activities that a user owns or has created, so I join it using `or`:

```
Activity.or(owner_id: 123).or(creator_id: 123).selector
# => {"$or"=>[{"owner_id"=>123}, {"creator_id"=>123}]}
```

Now I try to use CanCan on that.

```
Activity.accessible_by(current_ability)
# => {"$or"=>[{"privacy"=>"public"}, {"user_id"=>"51091cc977bb1eb27a000003"}]}
```

CanCan creates an `or` selector by default, as there are more than one rule in the ability.

It would be intuitive now to do just this:

```
Activity.or(owner_id: 123).or(creator_id: 123).accessible_by(current_ability)
# => {"$or"=>[{"owner_id"=>123}, {"creator_id"=>123}, {"privacy"=>"public"}, {"user_id"=>"51092b9777bb1ec385000003"}]}
```

But this joins the both `or` Arrays into one which is not what I want, so I did the following:

```
Activity.or(criteria).and(Activity.accessible_by(current_ability).selector).desc(:created_at)
# => {"$or"=>[{"owner_id"=>123}, {"creator_id"=>123}], "$and"=>[{"$or"=>[{"privacy"=>"public"}, {"user_id"=>"51092b9777bb1ec385000003"}]}]}
```

But this seems a bit unclean. Any idea on how to beautify this? Thank you.

PS: An afterthought: Should `accessible_by` not always return a `{'$and' => {'$or' => [...]}}` instead of only a {'$or' => [...]}?